# When is $(2^a-1)$ a power of 3

Tags: number-theory

I am looking to characterize the values of $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $(2^a-1)$ is an integral power of 3. In particular, are there any besides $a=1,2$? Any positive/negative results would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose $3^b=2^a-1$ for some integers $b,a$ with $a>2$. Reducing mod $8$, we have $3^b\equiv-1$. But the only powers of $3$ mod $8$ are easily seen to be $1$ and $3$, so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 9):

Those are the only solutions, as follows from [Catalan's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), proved by Mihailescu.

Comment: Talk about overkill... Look at anon's answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this wonderful theorem!

Comment: This is a great example of using a cannon to kill a mosquito, however!

Comment: It seems superfluous to invent an additional, small instrument to kill a mosquito, when you already have a cannon that will kill it and many other things. :-)